# Why does an enum implicitly convert to a std::string?

Tags: c++, enums

Sorry if this has been asked before or if I did something wrong in my code, but I just encountered a bug where I was assigning a wrong variable and it boils doing to this example:

```
#include <string>

enum Enum {
  A, B, C
};

int main() {
  std::string s = "A";

  if (s == "A")
    s = A;
  else if (s == "B")
    s = B;
  else if (s == "C")
    s = C;

  printf ("%s\n", s.c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

Note that in the if/else if statements I'm assigning to variable s (the actual example is converting "mode" into "mode_" where one is a string and one is an enum and I left off the underscore in one case.

My question is, why didn't the compiler complain? Even with -Wall and -W, it silently succeeds.

I feel like I'm missing something, or is it something off with my compiler? Is there anything in the standard on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard library includes the prototype

```
basic_string& operator=(charT c);
```

which means you can assign a single character to a string:

```
s = 'A';
```

But a single character is just a small integer, no?

You can avoid this problem with C++11-style scoped enumerators. The following will produce the expected compiler errors:

```
#include <string>

enum class Enum {
    A, B, C
};

int main() {
  std::string s = "A";

  if (s == "A")
    s = Enum::A;
  else if (s == "B")
    s = Enum::B;
  else if (s == "C")
    s = Enum::C;

  printf ("%s\n", s.c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well that's... an undesired side effect. That's exactly what's happening. If I set my enums to something like A = 600, B = 700, then it immediately complains that the value is too large to convert into a char without some overflow. Thanks!

Comment: @vmpstr: You can also use "scoped enumerator types"; eg. `enum class`

Comment: that's a good habit that I should get into. Plus it helps readability to do Enum::A instead of just A. Thanks again

Comment: @vmpstr: added to answer for posterity

Comment: Good to see the compiler can warn you if there'll be truncation, but I would've thought that almost all occasions of assigning an enum's value to a string would be warning worthy

Comment: @MattCoubrough: what about `enum Operator { plus = '+', minus = '-', times = '*'};` ? The enum is a compile-time constant and in this case it fits into a char, so there's nothing to warn about. My advice: use scoped enums.

Comment: You could also set the storage type of your `enum` to not be `char`

Comment: @Yakk: You could do that, but it doesn't mean you'll get a warning. The actual values of A, B and C are still small enough to fit into a char. (gcc-4.8, using `-Wall -Wextra`).

Comment: @jake: yes, the point was that if you use enum class, it will not compile. That is opposed to the similar code in the OP which compiles without a warning. The question was not "how do I do *X*" but rather "why does the compiler accept something obviuosly wrong".

Answer (score 2):

You are not comparing a string with a enum, you are comparing two strings.

However you are assigning an enum value to a string. Here the enum value (implicitly an integer) is implicitly converted to a char by the compiler, which can then be assigned to a std::string.

Comment: gee. I'm surprised there's not a compiler warning over that - does it constitue an implicit narrowing cast?

Comment: The compiler is allowed to do an implicit conversion in such cases (as it does for int to long etc...). The tricky thing is not the conversion but the fact that a char can be assigned to a string.

Comment: @karim, yeah it certainly caused me more grief than help